# Derivative of $\log x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If for the function $f$ there exists $g$ such that $g(f(x)) = x $, find the derivative of $g$.
Then use this for computing the derivative of $f(x) = \log(x)$

I tried this:

$(g(f(x)))´ =  g´(f(x))f´(x) = 1 $ then if  $f(x) = \log(x)$ then $$(g(\log(x)))´ =      g´(\log(x))(\log(x))´ = 1 $$ then $ f´(x) = (\log(x))´= \frac{1}{g´(\log(x))}$  but I'm stuck here. How can I conclude that the derivative of $\log(x)$ is $1/x$?

Comment: The notation is a bit confusing. You must know what's the derivative of the inverse function of the logarithm.

Comment: Hint: What is the inverse function for log?

Comment: is the exponential function

Comment: And the derivative of the inverse function (exponential function) is... which will be what your g'(x) will equal

Comment: sorry for my dumbs question but why i need the inverse function i only need g´(log x)

Comment: @Knight And $g$, by your definition, is the inverse function.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366563/how-to-integrate-1-x/1758952#1758952

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=\log(x)$ its inverse, then $f(g(x))=x$ and:
$$1=\frac{d}{dx}x=\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))=f'(g(x))g'(x)=xg'(x)$$
where we used $f'(x)=f(x)$. Thus we must have $g'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed like this.
**D/dx =1**

d/dx* e^{ln(x)}

Or e^{ln(x)}* d/dx*(lnx)=1

Or x *d/dx *ln(x)=1

**d/dx *ln(x)=1/x**

Hence proved.

Comment: It is hard to understand your answer.

Comment: I'm new to SE. So I don't really know how to put codes. However I changed the format. Is it okay now?